# Find indices of numpy array of array where entry is equal to array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an ndarray `Image` of size 100x100x3, i.e. 100 rows and 100 columns, where each entry is another array (RGB) value. I want to use `np.where` in order to find the indices of where the RGB array is equal to a predetermined value, e.g. `color1 = [43,234,45]`.

I have tried the following

```
indices = np.where(np.array_equal(image, color1))
```

but I always get the result

```
>print(indices)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

with values I know is in the array. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

`np.array_equal` is used to judge whether two arrays are completely equal. If you want to find a sub array, you can directly use the equal sign:

```
>>> ar = np.arange(2 * 2 * 3).reshape(2, 2, 3)
>>> ar
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]]])
>>> ar == [3, 4, 5]
array([[[False, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]]])
```

Use method `ndarray.all` or index to compress the results:

```
>>> (ar == [3, 4, 5]).all(-1)
array([[False,  True],
       [False, False]])
>>> (ar == [3, 4, 5])[..., 0]
array([[False,  True],
       [False, False]])
>>> mask = (ar == [3, 4, 5])[..., 0]
>>> mask.nonzero()
(array([0], dtype=int64), array([1], dtype=int64))
>>> np.where(mask)
(array([0], dtype=int64), array([1], dtype=int64))
```